# pandas replacing specific elements from a tseries datetimeindex

Tags: python, pandas

I have pandas object as:

```
df_days
DatetimeIndex(['2015-05-24', '2015-05-24', '2015-05-24',..., '2016-03-19',
               '2016-03-19', '2016-03-20'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=7224, freq=None)

type(df_days)
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
```

I have an array of indexes as:

```
hrIdx
(array([  23,   47,   71,   95,  119,  143,  167,  191,  215,  239,  263,
        287,  311,  335,  359,  383,  407,  431,  455,  479,  503,  527,
        551,  575,  599, ...,1592], dtype=int64),)
```

I am trying the following:

```
df_days[hrIdx] = df_days[hrIdx] + td(days=-1)
```

But the assignment operation fails. The right side operation of substracting a day works fine.

Error is:

```
    raise TypeError("Index does not support mutable operations")
TypeError: Index does not support mutable operations
```

What is proper way of changing only specific elements of `df_days` like I have tried to accomplish above?

Edit:

```
from datetime import timedelta as td
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referencing the pandas docs, I found this: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#id1

You can use this trick along with that code:

```
tdeltas = pd.TimedeltaIndex([str((0-int(i in hrIdx)))+' days' for i in xrange(len(df_days))])
```

and then:

```
df_days = df_days + tdeltas
```

**Note:** I'm looking at the docs from the latest version of pandas (0.19).